# Trigger based on profile name & custom permission set

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, user-profile, custom-permission

In my trigger I would need to make a condition according to the user profile as well as a custom permission set , and here is my code which does not deploy due to "Unexpected token" error .

```
trigger BeforeInsertCu on Strick__c (before insert) {

    Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
    
    Id currentUserProfileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
   
    String profileName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :currentUserProfileId].Name ;

    String permission =[SELECT DeveloperName   FROM CustomPermission  ]
    
        for( Strick__c ap : trigger.new) 
        {
            if (
                profileName =='Egypt' ||
                permission == 'PermissionEgypt'

            ){

            if(ap.Status__c == 'End' ) 
            
            {
                ap.Status__c.addError('The status can t be end in the creation');
            }
    
        
    }}
    }
```

Comment: @Ghingis Even If I tried what you say and I add the  `; ` and also change the type I get this error : ` Illegal assignment from String to Profile (7:13)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you are missing a `;` at the end of the line starting with `String permission`.
But there are more issues with your code like, that line won't return a String, but a CustomPermission, same with the previous line..

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use FeatureManagement to detect your custom permission:

```
String profileName = [SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()].Name;
Boolean hasEgyptPermission = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('PermissionEgypt');
for(Strick__c record: Trigger.new) {
  if( profileName == 'Egypt' && hasEgyptPermission && record.Status__c == 'End') {
    record.Status__c.addError('Cannot be "End" during record creation.');
}
```